# SQL Server cursor and foreachdb loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a cursor (without creating a temp table) to get all orphan users in my SQL Server instances. Here is what I've come up with:

```
Declare @Orphan_users table (username sysname)
DECLARE @orphan_users_cursor CURSOR  
set @orphan_users_cursor = cursor 
FOR
select * from (
insert into @Orphan_users 
set EXEC SP_MSFOREACHDB' USE [?]
SELECT dp.name  
FROM sys.database_principals AS dp  
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp  
    ON dp.SID = sp.SID  
WHERE sp.SID IS NULL  
    AND authentication_type_desc = ''INSTANCE'''--) 

OPEN @orphan_users_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @orphan_users_cursor INTO  @Orphan_users
```

Comment: Try this post from Aaron Bertrand: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your table should also include the database name, otherwise once you identify a user that is abandoned in *some* database on your system, how are you going to find them?

Anyway here is a way to do it by building a single query rather than executing a query database by database (and relying on a system procedure that is undocumented, unsupported, and has community replacements because it's so buggy). It isn't better or faster, just easier to understand and troubleshoot, IMHO.

```
DECLARE @AbandonedUsers TABLE(db sysname, username sysname);

DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT db = NULL, username = NULL WHERE 1 = 0',
        @base nvarchar(max) = N'
UNION ALL SELECT PARSENAME(N''$qn$'',1), dp.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  FROM $qn$.sys.database_principals AS dp
  WHERE dp.authentication_type = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_principals AS sp
      WHERE sp.SID = dp.SID)';

SELECT @sql += REPLACE(@base,N'$qn$',QUOTENAME(name))
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE state = 0; -- might also add AND database_id > 4 to avoid common system DBs

INSERT @AbandonedUsers(db, username) EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT db, username FROM @AbandonedUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to reinvent the wheel. If you want a pure tsql based approach - use [`sp_ineachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/) as suggested by @Dan.

I would suggest you use dbatools - [`Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser)

e.g. Below command Finds and repairs all orphan users of all databases present on server 'sql2017'

> Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser -SqlInstance sql2017

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. The problem is I can't create any persistent or temporally object into the database. I know it could be easily done using a temp table. But my project doesn't allow me doing that.

Comment: What about using powershell based - repair-dbadborphaneduser ?

Comment: The requirement is using SQL only. Its is one of the rules I am developing for database hardening.

Comment: @AiB Your project allows you to call `sp_msforeachdb` but doesn't allow you to create a #temp table? And you can use any SQL you want but nothing vetted by the community and maintained in GitHub?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is right. I am not allowed to create anything even a temp table. I saw your post in mssqltip. Unfortunately, i can't create a stored procedure either. But I can call any system procedures that comes with sql server

Comment: @AiB Sounds like a silly set of restrictions with no basis of justification in reality. Do they want you to do your job, or not?